# How to include GCM/FCM in an android library module?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-library, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am not able to generate google-services json for an android library because its asking for the application id. I know how to add it in a project.

Comment: Libraries don't have application ID. Application ID is supplied by the consumer of your library. Just include the dependency and that's it. Don't apply the google services plugin on a library.

Comment: @Eugen I want to create a library which can show notifications to the user. Even if the app has a gcm setup, my library should be able to generate a gcm token different from the app( gcm server also will be different). My library should be independent of the app

Answer (score 7):

## FCM client setup

Libraries don't have an application ID. Application ID is supplied by the consumer of your library. Just include the dependency and that's it. Don't apply the google services plugin on a library.

Your client would have presumably followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client tutorial. Which means you have to create your library's push message processor to which your client will delegate work. Example:

**your.client.app.package.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService() : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(p0)

        // Your client's message handling.
        // ...

        // If not handled by client, delegate to library.
        AwesomeLibrary.processPushMessage(this, p0)
}
```

**your.awesome.library.package.fcm.AwesomeLibraryFcm.kt**

```
object AwesomeLibraryFcm {
    fun processPushMessage(context: Context, message: RemoteMessage) {
        // TODO Your job.
    }
}
```

As you can see connecting Firebase to your library is handled entirely by your library's consumer. You don't touch Firebase on client side at all.

## FCM server setup

You need an application ID to setup FCM. One application ID can only be associated to one Firebase Project, which would be that of your library's consumer. Dead end.

If you're running an *online service* and need to send push messages *on behalf of your client* you need them to create a **Server key** (restricted to your server's IP address) in Google Dev console and upload it along with **Project ID** to your server. These would allow your server to send push messages. This is essentially your client *giving you permission to send push mesages on their behalf*.

Mind potential security risks and abuse of your service.

Comment: The FCM Server setup described in the answer can be summarized as:
"ask your user to create a sender-id / server-key and to give that to you".

There is also a second possibility for the FCM server setup:
1. can create a firebase project for your library.
2. do-not add the google-service.json to the library.. each app should add its own
3. you can still create a token for the sender-id of your library-firebase-project using the API: firebaseInstanceId.getToken("sender-id-2", "FCM")
4. for the client setup the instructions above are correct.

Comment: @eugen This is exactly what i ended up in doing and i have done it before asking this question. But i don't want to depend on my client for pushing notifications. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini this is what i need. Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini If you have a solution, post it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Eugen: your answer is already pretty clear. Feel free to add my comment to your answer if you like it.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini My answer is wrongly based on premise that you need to associate Android application ID to a Firebase project whose FCM you're using. According to [this article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008) I was wrong. Please provide a full answer around your idea to "get token for a second sender".

Answer (score 1):

I integrated FCM in library project and used that library in a new app project.
I copied google service json file from library and paste it in new app project's app module.
After this I modified this google service `json` file. I renamed`"package_name"` under `"client_info"` to app package name and I was able to get notification.